# Replace multiple lines while retaining spacing and indentation with Ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

## Background

I have the following snippet in a `composer.json` file:

```
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

Using Chef, I'd like use a `ruby_block` to replace this content with:

```
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override",
    "patches-file": "m2-hotfixes/patches.json"
}
```

## Question

What's the best way to achieve this using ruby so that I retain the proper indentation and spacing, etc?  The `gsub` examples I have seen would result in everything on a single line which is not what I want.  (E.g. if I searched for: `/"magento-force/": /"override"/` and then replaced it with `/"magento-force/": /"override"/, /"patches-file/": /"m2-hotfixes/patches.json/"`, I'd likely get something like:

```
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override", "patches-file": "m2-hotfixes/patches.json"
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to retain the indentation and white space? What do you do with the changed hash? Why don't you just read and parse that JSON file, update the hash in Ruby and write the changed JSON back?

Comment: Yeah, that might be the best way to go.  Turns out that for this specific need, there's an even easier way which is to use composer itself to achieve what I want.  I'll add that as an an answer, but if you'd like to post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the *best* way to achieve the exact task I want is to use composer itself.  Using this in an execute resource gets me exactly what I need:

```
config extra.patches-file m2-hotfixes/patches.json
```

That said, I won't consider this a pure answer to the question posed.